# Is there a formula for a sequence like $k^{t}-k^{t-1}+k^{t-2}-...+k^{2}-k^{1}+k^{0}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, exponentiation

I am trying to solve a programming problem and my intended solution involves a calculation like this one:

$k^{t}-k^{t-1}+k^{t-2}-...+k^{2}-k^{1}+k^{0}$

The problem is that $t$ can be as large as $1,414,213,562$ so iterating isn't an option. Does anyone know of a formula for this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: This looks like an alternating geometric sequence to me.

Comment: Hint: The ratio between terms (r) is $-k$. The formula for geometric sum is $\frac{t_{1}\left( 1-r^{n} \right)}{1-r}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You look for
$$\sum_{p=0}^t (-k)^p=\frac{1-(-k)^{t+1}}{1+k}$$

Comment: Morning Sami. :+)

Comment: $\ddot \cup +1$